# why doesn't this visNetwork in R show edge

Tags: r, graph, visnetwork

I'm exploring visNetwork and can't figure out why this one doesn't show edge

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes=data.frame(node=c('m1','m2','n1','n2'))
a=data.frame(x=c('n1','n2'),y=c('m1','m2'))
links=a%>% group_by(x,y)%>%tally()
visNetwork(nodes, links)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `?visNetwork`:

> nodes: data.frame with nodes informations. Needed at least column "id".
>   edges: data.frame with edges informations. Needed at least
>   columns "from" and "to".

So

```
visNetwork(
  setNames(nodes, "id"),
  setNames(links, c("from", "to", "foo"))
)
```

will work.