# visNetwork edges not displayed

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a network using visNetwork. However, the edges are not being displayed. There is a very similar question in stackoverflow regarding this. But the solution mentioned there does not apply to my case. Any help would be great. The following are the the nodes and edges data set that need to be plotted.

[why doesn't this visNetwork in R show edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169336/why-doesnt-this-visnetwork-in-r-show-edge)

```
nodes_CTP

   ID         label
1   0         order
2   1       details
3   2           tab
4   3      displays
5   4       profile
6   5        window
7   6        status
8   7          sign
9   8   powerorders
10  9        detail
11 10        button
12 11  prerequisite
13 12          icon
14 13 prerequisites
15 14         chart
16 15       control
17 16         entry
18 17     encounter
19 18        change
20 19        verify
21 20       purpose    

links_CTP

   from to value
1     0  1  0.55
2     0  2  0.53
3     0  3  0.50
4     0  4  0.50
5     0  5  0.49
6     0  6  0.48
7     0  7  0.44
8     0  8  0.43
9     0  9  0.42
10    0 10  0.41
11    0 11  0.39
12    0 12  0.39
13    0 13  0.38
14    0 14  0.38
15    0 15  0.38
16    0 16  0.37
17    0 17  0.37
18    0 18  0.37
19    0 19  0.37
20    0 20  0.37

library(visNetwork)

 visNetwork(nodes_CTP, links_CTP, height = "700px", width = "100%") %>%
  visOptions(selectedBy = "label", 
         highlightNearest = TRUE, 
         nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
  visPhysics(stabilization = FALSE)
```

Comment: "similar question in stackoverflow regarding this" - please add the weblink.

Comment: Did you try renaming "ID" to "id" as suggested in linked post?

Comment: @zx8754- Yes..but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

This work fine for me. Verify data format (class and names).

```
library(visNetwork)

nodes_CTP <- data.frame(id = 0:20, label = LETTERS[1:21])


links_CTP <- data.frame(from = 0, to = 1:20, 
                        value = seq(0.35, 0.5, length.out = 20))


visNetwork(nodes_CTP, links_CTP, height = "700px", width = "100%") %>%
  visOptions(selectedBy = "label", 
             highlightNearest = TRUE, 
             nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
  visPhysics(stabilization = FALSE)
```